# Testing a Score Range in C#

Tags: c#, class

I am trying to create a class that test a credit score range in C#. Was hoping that if the range was selected in an if else statement then I could return valid or invalid.

The class is pulling score from another calls that gets and stores the class, then will run the score and validate whether or not if it is validated, by being in the range of 300 to 850, however before I could finish this VS was yelling a lot of curse words at me.

Thank you

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication34
{
//test score and returns valid if below 300 or above 850.
//
    class CreditScoreEngine
    {
        public int TestScore() 
        {
            int score = 0;
            if (score >= 300 && score <= 850) 
                score = Convert.ToString("valid") 
            else (string = "invalid")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? "VS was yelling a lot of curse words at me" - I really doubt this is the case. Reading and understanding error messages is the first step to solving problems - and copying the error message you are having an issue with into your question is the first step at getting a useful answer here on SO.

Comment: The only thing you're showing in your question is you have an if statement that will never fire. Other than the desire to do something that you describe, you're not give the fine people here on SO anything that they can work with to provide you an answer.

Comment: My goal was to be able to create a range then if the range was satisfied return a value of valid, everything else outside that range would be invalid.  Then I would be able to do something else in another class.

Answer (score 1):

There are several things that are so very wrong with this code.

- You have defined your variable `score` as an int. You then try to assign it a value via `Convert.ToString`, which returns a string. The compiler won't allow you to assign a value of one type to a variable of a completely unrelated type.
- `else` does not take a conditional, as it runs if the conditional within its previous `if` returns false. You either meant to use curly braces instead of parentheses, or you meant to use an `else if`.
- `string` is a type, not a variable. Saying `string = ???` doesn't make any syntactical sense - you can't reassign a type. (Perhaps you meant `score` instead of `string`.)
- If you did mean to use an `else if`, you need the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`. An easy way to remember which is which is that `=` means "equals" and `==` means "is equal to" (the longer operator has the longer meaning).
- Subsequently, if you meant to use `else if`, then the `else if` needs a body.
- Functionally, this function is supposed to test if a score is within a given range (specified to be 300-850). However, you are hard-coding the value of `score` to be 0, so this function isn't going to be testing anything. You either need to add input to this function by way of `Console.ReadLine` or change the function to take a parameter.
- Furthermore, this function checks if the score is within a particular range or not, which implies that the return value will be `bool`. If the function is meant to operate on its own, it could also have a return value of `void`. But you have specified that it has a return value of `int`, which unless there's something you forgot to mention doesn't make any sense.
- Also, if you *do* want the function to have a non-void return value, your function isn't currently returning anything.

For example, your desired code might look something like this:

```
public bool TestScore(int score) 
{
    if (score >= 300 && score <= 850) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, it could look like this:

```
public void TestScore()
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    int score;

    if (int.TryParse(input, out score))
    {
        if (score >= 300 && score <= 850)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The score passes.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The score fails.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The score is not in the correct format.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to follow and your example code does not make logical sense.  However, I think you are trying to do something like this:

```
public bool isValid(int score) { return score >= 300 && score <= 580;}
```

Comment: Thank you, new to both SO and coding in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
//rewrite the code using this
public string TestScore(int score)
{
   //I believe it would be more appropiate if you would return a boolean
   //instead of a string.

   return (score>=300 && score<=850)?"valid":"invalid";
}
```